# obtain current day using chrono

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

C++11 provide a function to return current time. However, I cannot find there is a function to return current day. And I use boost to do so.

```
boost::gregorian::date TODAY = boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
```

Is there any way to achieve the same result using chrono?

EDIT: What I want is to use time_point to represent current day. That means the hour,minute and second are zero 2013-07-31 00:00:00

Comment: By day do you mean "mon","wens", ...

Comment: No, chrono is for time/timing.

Comment: @aaronman What I want is to use time_point to represent current day. That means the hour,minute and second are zero 2013-07-31 00:00:00

Comment: maybe you want [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chronos doesn't extend to date issues; that's really not it's purpose. The dividing line between date issues and "time" issues is the day. And Chrono doesn't define a day type.

But you could just divide the time in hours by 24. Or even better, define your own duration typedef and use that:

```
typedef std::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<3600 * 24>> day;
```

Then just [use a `time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) with that type:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, day> day_getter;
day_getter.time_since_epoch();
```

Comment: Here are some algorithms designed to convert between `system_clock::time_point` and a `year/month/day` triple, and can further be used to get the time of day, without going through `time_t` and the C API.  It uses the `day` typedef outlined in this answer (though it is called `days` instead to be consistent with `chrono::hours`, `chrono::minutes`, etc.).  These algorithms are intended to enable clients to easily extend `chrono` to date issues.  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html